# Is it possible to connect a second wifi card to a raspberry pi 3, VNC to it using one and then use the second to connect to another wifi?

Tags: wifi, pi-3, vnc, android

I'd like to connect to VNC via my android smartphone and then be able to use an external wifi card to connect to another WiFi.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make independent use of as many NICs as you can attach.

However, all routes must go through one particular interface or another, so if you have two of them connected to the internet at large, then you will have to decide which addresses are going to be routed which way.  The normal way to do this is to prioritize specialized ranges and then let anything else fall through to a default route.

Comment: i'd like the first one (let's say wlan0) not to be connected to the internet, and the second one (let's say wlan1), to be connected to the internet. Is there a "guide", somewhere from which I can learn how to do it? Even just some topics to research.

Comment: The first thing would be to ditch "raspberry pi" from your search terms, since the means is OS specific, and not much to do with the brand of hardware.  Raspbian was created for the Pi, but it's a slight variant of Debian, a GNU/Linux distro which has been around for a few decades -- so you want to look for information about "linux" and or "Debian".  I believe you should be able to do this mostly via the `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration (I opted out of that stuff a long time ago so can't say much about the specifics), although it sounds like a hotspot may also be involved.

Comment: My description above isn't even OS specific, it's based on general IP networking concepts.  If you want to edit your question to explain in more detail exactly what you want to do I can elaborate on that.  There's always the chance someone will come along with a configuration that works for you but I would not hold your breath; beyond that I think this is something best done one step at a time via experimentation/trial & error.  If you add those details to the question I can also summarize what those steps might be.

Answer (score 0):

You can use external card to connect to another network. I have done this, although it is not without its problems.

As goldilocks has indicated there are routing issues. You may also find the interfaces are not always allocated to the same `wlan0` or `wlan1`. This can be solved by writing `udev` rules (but this is somewhat complex).